# How to draw a piechart in iPhone

Tags: iphone

I want to draw a piechart in my application. Do anyone know any code or tutorial to help me out. I found some in the following link
http://rajeev.name/blog/2009/01/18/drawing-pie-charts-using-iphone-sdk/

but if there is any other more efficient way to do it, I want to learn it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you know how to do pie charts on other platforms, but there really are some basic techniques that you should be aware of and understand, before embarking on creating pie charts on ANY platform.

See [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/julijanpiechart.aspx) for a pretty good discussion.  There are many more out there, if you want to learn more.

Applying that to the iPhone isn't going to be child's play, but it's not too hard either.  If you are looking for a library to do the work for you, look around and you'd probably find something to give you a head start.

Answer (score 1):

KeepEdge offers an iPhone charting/graphing API:

http://www.keepedge.com/products/iphone_charting/

You can also check the source code of AppMobile, which has a pie chart embedded inside it:

http://github.com/omz/AppSales-Mobile/tree/master

Answer (score 1):

I will recommend you to look at the ["Animating Pie Slices Using a Custom CALayer"](http://blog.pixelingene.com/2012/02/animating-pie-slices-using-a-custom-calayer/) page!.

Answer (score 0):

there is new, nice Pie Chart 3D library. 3D charts which you can rotate and scale with fingers + protocol for getting information about tapped slice

http://iphone.orpi.pl/?p=20